# get matrix of image in opencv

Tags: opencv, matrix

```
    //Open the image 
    Mat img_rgb = imread("sudoku2.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE); 
    if (img_rgb.empty()) 
    { 
            cout<<"Cannot open the image"<<endl; 
            return; 
    }
    Mat img_bw = img_rgb > 128;
    imwrite("image_bw.jpg", img_bw);
```

Now, I want to get all pixels of img_bw and save it into a matrix M (*int[img_bw.rows][img_bw.cols]*). How to do it in C++.

Answer (score 0):

What format ?

The raw byte data in cv::Mat is available from the .ptr() function, ie img_bw.ptr().

Opencv also has an xml and json read and write functions for matrices, just by using the << operator - see [opencv tutorial on xml and yaml i/o](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/file_input_output_with_xml_yml/file_input_output_with_xml_yml.html#fileinputoutputxmlyaml)

EDIT: In c++ you can access pixels with the .at operator.

Use `img_data.at<uchar>(x,y)` for an unsigned char (CV_8U) pixel and `img_data.at<float>(x,y)` for a CV_32F image.

Comment: I mean how to get a pixel at a random position :D. Sorry my bad expressing.